# How to combine 2 text files into a new file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two text files that haves columns of data for each of them. I am wondering if there is a way to combine both files together so that specific or all columns are side by side? Can this be done using append?

Comment: You should show few lines from the files. It is difficult to guess otherwise. If you mean to use `.readlines()` to get the lists of lines then no, append will not help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read both files, put the data in a dictionary by key, and again use the csv module to write a file with the joined data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your two files have the exact same amount of lines, you could do something like this:

```
# column 0 in right file next to column 0 in left file
# column 1 in right file next to column 1 in left file
# column 2 in right file next to column 2 in left file
order = (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)
contents = [] # contains left side file content in idx 0, right side in idx 1
for fname in ("leftfile", "rightfile"):
    with open(fname) as f:
        contents.append(f.readlines()) # read entire file content

separator = " " # what separates the columns?
with open("out", "w") as outfile:
    for row in range(len(contents[0])):
        cl = contents[0][row].strip().split(separator) # columns in left file
        cr = contents[1][row].strip().split(separator) # columns in right file
        outfile.writelines(
                separator.join("%s%s%s" % (cl[l], separator, cr[r])
                    for l, r in order))
        outfile.write("\n")
```

This reads both files (called `leftfile` and `rightfile`) into memory, strips each line in both files of leading/trailing whitespaces, and splits them by the given `separator`.
The columns are then rearranged, put back together and written to the output file.
You can control the order of which the columns in each file are put next to each other by altering the `order` tuple.